# Xamarin: Assembly reference does not exist

Tags: android, xamarin, reference, addition

I have a problem referencing the reference to my other project.

I have a solution with two project.

One of them is the main application and other one contain a service which I wanted to separate with the main one. The service was created as a class library instead of and android application.

I have added the reference of the main application to the Project contains the service. When I compiled the Service Project, I receive an error saying :

> The type or namespace name 'MainApp' does not exist in the namespace.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting Xamarin Studio, seems to not find new projects some of time.

Comment: One question: If I only have a service in the separate application independent with the main application which contains all the activities, do I still need to setup the application as android application for the service or android library.

Comment: Still not working. Is it because the main application project isn't a library.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your main application project ("Launcher" I think?) should be referencing the class library project with your service - not the other way around.

This also means that the code in your class library project cannot reference or make calls directly to the code in your main project. Otherwise that would be a circular reference.